# Why is the radius of curvature = 1/(curvature)?

Tags: calculus, geometry, curvature, tangent-line, arc-length

My textbook *Thomas' Calculus (14th edition)* initially defines **curvature** as the **magnitude** of change of **direction of tangent** with respect to the  **arc length** of the curve (|d**T**/ds|, where **T** is the tangent vector and s is the arc length) and later by intuition conclude that κ = 1/ρ (where, κ=curvature,ρ = radius).

Is there a way to prove this equation mathematically ?

Edit:
If curvature was defined as the inverse of radius of curvature, then how does the textbook define and derive an expression of curvature first and then provide a relationship between it and the radius of curvature.

Comment: I don't think so, the curvature is defined as the inverse of the radius, it is more of a mathematical definition. Intuitively, when the radius goes to infinity, then the curvature goes to zero (straight line).

Comment: To get some intuition: [Curvature of plane curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_plane_curves)

Comment: @RockyRock considering curvature was defined like that(definition in my textbook), a problem arises because radius of curvature is the radius of an imaginary circle of which the arc of the curve is a part of, and it seems that radius of curvature is a more basic property.

Comment: I think what you're really asking is, why is the curvature of a circle equal to the reciprocal of the radius?

Comment: Traditionally, the curvature was defined as the inverse of the radius of the [*osculating circle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle). Your book uses a different characterization.

Comment: This can certainly be proved—or, at least, *justified* with a theorem. We just need to prove that by the given definition of "radius of curvature", the radius of curvature of a circle is equal to its radius.

Comment: @egreg The idea to compute the  curvature of a curve with osculating circles is to compare its curvature with a standard-curve, here a circle.  An old idea, already presented by Kepler, Descartes and Newton (1671/72).  But this is not a geometric, an intrinsic definition of curvature.  This was first given by Euler (1775) who defines curvature as the limit of the tangent’s direction compared to the length of the curve.  Indeed these two characterizations differ essential.  (BTW Euler’s geometric idea was a basic insight to develop curvature of Riemannian manifolds in higher dimensions.)

Answer (score 1):

Without much calculation (but also without dealing with exceptional cases, such as the tangent being vertical, or the second derivative being zero):

By the definition given at the start of the question, and by the chain rule, the curvature of $y = f(x)$ at $x$ is: $$\left\lvert\frac{(d/dx)\tan^{-1}f'(x)}{ds/dx}\right\rvert,$$
where $s$ is arc length. Since $ds/dx = \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}$, the curvature depends only on $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$.

Therefore, if functions $f, g$ have second order contact at $x$, i.e. $f(x) = g(x)$, $f'(x) = g'(x)$, and $f''(x) = g''(x)$, then $f, g$ will have the same curvature at $x$.

If the graph of $g$ is a circle, then its curvature is the same as the magnitude of the rate of change of the direction of the radius with respect to arc length (because the tangent at a point is perpendicular to the radius to that point). But if the radius has length $r$, and makes an angle $\theta$ with a fixed line, then the length of the arc from the point of intersection of the circle with that line is $r\theta$, therefore the curvature is $1/r$.

It is enough, then, to prove that if $f''(x) \ne 0$, there exists a circle $g$ having second order contact with $f$ at $x$.

Proceeding similarly to Hardy, *A Course of Pure Mathematics* (10th ed. 1952, p. 299), but leaving out the explicit formulae, which we don't need (although they're simple enough, and the expression for $r$ gives the same result as the defining expression in the second paragraph above):

Writing $y = f(x)$, $\dot{y} = f'(x)$, $\ddot{y} = f''(x)$, so that also $y = g(x)$, $\dot{y} = g'(x)$, $\ddot{y} = g''(x)$ (with a suitable function $g$ to be found), we require a circle centre $(p, q)$, radius $r$, such that:
\begin{align*}
(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 & = r^2, \\
(x - p) + (y - q)\dot{y} & = 0, \\
1 + \dot{y}^2 + (y - q)\ddot{y} & = 0.
\end{align*}
Because $\ddot{y} \ne 0$, the third equation can be solved for $q$, then the second equation can be solved for $p$, and finally the first equation can be solved for $r$. So the required circle exists. $\square$

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression that curvature = 1/r ?

Comment: Because the arc length is $s = r\theta$, the curvature is $|d\theta/ds| = |d(s/r)/ds| = |1/r| = 1/r$.

Comment: A correction I meant to make while composing, but forgot: we seek a function $g$ representing a circular arc. It cannot represent a whole circle, because then it would have to be "two-valued", which is nonsense. To represent an arc of a circle with centre $(p, q)$ and radius $r>0$, such a function $g$ must satisfy the condition $(x - p)^2 + (g(x) - q)^2 = r^2$. Differentiating with respect to $x$, and then taking a given fixed value of $x$, and requiring $g(x) = y$, $g'(x) = \dot{y}$, and $g''(x) = \ddot{y}$ (values known from the given function $f$), we get the stated equations for $p, q, r$.

Comment: I also forgot to include an initial step in the argument: if $\theta = \tan^{-1}f'(x)$, then $\mathbf{T} = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, therefore $|d\mathbf{T}/ds| = |(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)(d\theta/ds)| = |d\theta/ds|$.